# How can I position a label in the top 66% of a Grid with C#

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using this C# code to create a grid with a Label inside and then add it to the details element:

```
details.Children.Clear();
var grid = new Grid()
{
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    Margin = new Thickness(60, 20, 60, 20)
};
grid.Children.Add(new Label
{
    Text = msg,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    TextColor = (Color) Application.Current.Resources["FooterTextColor"],
    Style = (Style)footerText
});
details.Children.Add(grid);
```

This works but what I would like to have is a label that is not in the center (as it is now) but in the center of the top 2/3 of the grid.

Can anyone give me advice on how I can do this?

Comment: use another Layout container within your Grid to align the Label, or use Padding/Margin settings to align the Label, etc

Comment: Using another layout sounds like a good solution but I am not sure how to do this in C#.  I think Padding / Margin might not work in my case as I want it to be a proportion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add `RowDefinitions` to the `Grid`:

```cs
grid.RowDefinitions.Add (new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength (2, GridUnitType.Star) });
grid.RowDefinitions.Add (new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength (1, GridUnitType.Star) });
```

Note the `GridLength`: it splits the grid height 2:1 between the first row and second row.

You can then assign your label to the first row:

```cs
Label myLabel = new Label
{
    Text = msg,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    TextColor = (Color) Application.Current.Resources["FooterTextColor"],
    Style = (Style)footerText
};

grid.Children.Add(myLabel, 0, 0); // Split (view, row, column)
```